# Reference entire column, not just one cell Google Sheets

Tags: notifications, google-sheets

The following will send email notification if F6 is edited on a google sheet. I need help making it send a notification if any cell in column F is edited, not just one cell. I tried ('F6,F7, etc) and I tried F:F, those don't work.

```
        function emailNotification(e) { 
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || e.range.getA1Notation() !== ('F6')) return;
     return;
    var recipient = "mail@google.com";
    var subject = 'SUBJECT';
    var body = ' BODY OF MAIL ';
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
    };
```

Please help, I don't know where I'm going wrong. Otherwise the script works like a charm for a single cell. Just not the whole column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will run code if any cell in column F of Sheet1 is edited.

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName= sheet.getSheetName();
  if(sheetName=="Sheet1"){
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
  var range = sheet.getRange("F1:F"+lr);
  var rangeRowStart = range.getRow();
  var rangeRowEnd = rangeRowStart + range.getHeight()-1;
  var rangeColStart = range.getColumn();
  var rangeColEnd = rangeColStart + range.getWidth()-1;
  if (editRow >= rangeRowStart && editRow <= rangeRowEnd 
  && editCol >= rangeColStart && editCol <= rangeColEnd)
  {

  Logger.log("Run Code")
 //YOUR CODE HERE
 }}}
```

Comment: Works Perfect!! THANK YOU ED!!

Comment: Glad it works for you, Tony. Could you please approve the answer? Thanks.